# Signalr 2.4 on Shared Hosting

Tags: signalr

I am using Signalr 2.4 to broadcast a game loop. My signalr hub has a public static list of broadcasters like so: `public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, CribbageBroadcaster> _cribbageBroadcasters = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CribbageBroadcaster>();`

I am getting some strange issues once I deploy my app my shared hosting provider. I have two methods that try and get the count of broadcasters. In my controller I get the count like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(DataSourceRequest dsr)
        {
            var viewModel = new HomePageViewModel();
            viewModel.Standings = _standingsListFactory.CreateStandings(dsr);
            viewModel.GamesBeingPlayed = CribbageHub._cribbageBroadcasters.Count;
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

And another method on the hub itself which I call using javascript :

```
 public int GetGameCount()
        {
            return _cribbageBroadcasters.Count;
        }
```

I tested these methods locally using multiple browsers and it works perfectly, with both returning the expected number of games. However, once I deploy my code sometimes one method will give a count but the other one wont. Other times both will say 0 when I know there should be one 1. And other times it will display the correct count. Each time I refresh the page the result is different. I am lost as to what is causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing your deployment, it is hard to be certain. However, it sounds like maybe there is some kind of load balancer that is creating multiple instances of your contoller.

Comment: @SouthShoreAK Thanks for commenting. I am using a2hosting. I will look into using signalr on a load balanced servers to see if this clears up this strange issue.

Comment: Hi @BrandonSpor. Any update on this? Was share hosting the problem?

Comment: @IkelieCyril Shared hosting was the problem. I did try this solution (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server), but it ended up being too slow for my purposes, although it did fix the issue. I believe redis scaleout is the correct solution but was too costly for my use case.